# HTML table into imges

Tags: javascript, arrays, swap

I want to write JavaScript code to read the information from an array, and to represent it as an HTML table, and then to replace specific elements with specific images.

I think I need to loop through the two-dimensional array and use swap-case, and, for example, if the current element is " ", then to swap it with a specific image.

The two-dimensional array is like this.

HTML:

```
<table id="table" border="10">         
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
var array = [["h", " ", "tl", " ", "sl", " "],
                 ["b", "tl", " ", " ", "sl", " "],
                 ["t", " ", " ", " ", "sl", " "],
                 [" ", "sl", " ", " ", " ", "s"],
                 [" ", "sl", " ", " ", "tl", "b"],
                 [" ", "sl", " ", "tl", " ", "t"]],
    table = document.getElementById("table");

for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = array[i][j];
  }
}
```

the switching is like this:

" " = https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574967925254127659/empty.png

"h" = https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574968068187488256/head.jpg

"b" = https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574968145719197707/body.jpg

"t" = https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574968236060180481/tail.jpg

"sl" = https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574968327948992522/standing_ladder.jpg

"tl" = https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574968405011202078/tilted_ladder.jpg

Sorry to dump the question like this, but I'm still new and this is destroying me.

Comment: *"...if the current element is " " then to swap..."*: you mean a space must be replaced? By which image? And "B" also? Do you have the list of images as they correspond to the strings?

Comment: Yeah, for each empty element there is a specific picture that should replace it, and the same for the rest of the elements, and at the end it will display like a big board of pictures.

The problem is I have no Idea how to do so, ogogle search didnt help, so thought maybe I could ask here.
Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: Could you add to the question which are the pictures for each case?

Comment: I edited it, its kind of like snakes and ladders, but just the pictures :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object keyed by the codes and with the corresponding image URLs as values:

```js
var array = [["h", " ", "tl", " ", "sl", " "],
                 ["b", "tl", " ", " ", "sl", " "],
                 ["t", " ", " ", " ", "sl", " "],
                 [" ", "sl", " ", " ", " ", "sl"],
                 [" ", "sl", " ", " ", "tl", "b"],
                 [" ", "sl", " ", "tl", " ", "t"]],
    table = document.getElementById("table"),
    map = {
        " ": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574967925254127659/empty.png",
        "h": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574968068187488256/head.jpg",
        "b": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574968145719197707/body.jpg",
        "t": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574968236060180481/tail.jpg",
        "sl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574968327948992522/standing_ladder.jpg",
        "tl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/394449403911471105/574968405011202078/tilted_ladder.jpg"
    };
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
        var cell = row.cells[j];
        cell.innerHTML = ""; // remove what was there before
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = map[array[i][j]]; // retrieve & set the image location
        cell.appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="10">         
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That works :D thanks a lot :)
I have another question, when I asked a friend about it he told me to do something like this: 
switch(currentcell)
{
//some code...
case s:
    mytable.cell.innerHTML = '<img src="images/snake_head.png">';
//some more code 
}

Is it right? or it's less convenient? 
Thank you for your help :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, that is another possibility, but I am not a fan of `switch`, and when you set `innerHTML` you should really escape a few special characters ( `<` and `&`) although it will work without in most cases.